# How do I resolve Jquery.load() deprecated warning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jquery.load feature for loading page to div on several pages of my project and I keep getting deprecated warning in console. Please how can I resolve this?

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

```
  <script>
    $(document).on('change', 'select#class_id', function () {
        var class_id = $(this).val();
        $('p#content').load('class.php?cid='+class_id);
    });
</script>
```

Need help using this

```
$("p#content").on("load", function() {
    //url
});
```

Is there a way to load these pages without warning.

Comment: use `$.get(url, data, success)` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: @SimonHänisch How would that fix warning?

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: `$('p#content').load('class.php');` and `$("p#content").on("load", function() {...])` are two different things: [first one](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [second one](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: Be aware, your best bet would be to upgrade to jq 3.x

Comment: yeah i am using jquery 3.1 but have little knowledge on these errors, I thought the error was being triggered by the load(). I will just have to switch and refactor my code to `$.get`

Comment: @Mysterio4 Humm, i don't see how switching your code to  `$.get` would remove this warning

Comment: Then that's a lot for me to handle. I do not know what to do about that cause its just 3 lines of javascript code on that page

Comment: BUT have you try as in dupe: `$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});` before you bind `change()` event???  This would make the warning disappear but you could face other issue regarding targeted page script being loaded asynchronously